# Breakpoint installation failed: Interrupt failed

Tags: c++, eclipse, debugging, breakpoints

I'm using Eclipse Mars and trying to debug a C++ file. I'm adding a breakpoint to a line, but after a few seconds I get the warning:

> Breakpoint installation failed: Interrupt failed.

And the debugger doesn't stop at that point even though I know for sure that the code does reach the line with the breakpoint.

What can be done to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This messages indicates that the source file where you set the breakpoint does not belong to the actual binary you are debugging

Comment: Try debugging the binary which is associated with your source file.
You have to find out where your source file is being used.
looks like you have a common source for multiple binaries.

Comment: I'm not sure how.. I'm simply running the code and know it reaches that breakpoint. How can I find the binary and what then?

Comment: take a look at this https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/201329/

There are some workarounds mentioned.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84655/discussion-between-nishant-and-yonatan-nir).

Answer (score 1):

The error message says: "interrupt failed". This does not seems to be a problem with matching binary with source file, it is rather a problem with GDB not being able to interrupt the process. My suggestion is to restart the debugger and set the breakpoint before the program actually starts.

I have this error sometimes when I debug a C++ multithreaded program in Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

Although I hadn't encountered such a problem with Eclipse, my suggestion is to look to Eclipse forum following these links:

1. https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=201329#page_top
2. https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=331833

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that "Skip All Breakpoints" is not enabled!

[skip breakpoints button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUeLd.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've had this warning on Eclipse TrueStudio Atollic. It didn't hamper at all my debugging. I rebuilt, checked breakpoint properties unsuccesfully. Then I remained in Eclipse ide, closed the project, reopened it and the warning had disappeared.